# Why is the .JPG files ignored and output is .JPEG file not found? Thus the program should look for .jpg and not .jpeg

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I am trying to modify the .JPEG files contains in the static/temp folder to make sure they are corrupted but the targeted files are ignored. The Goal is to change or inject data in the files to make it unrecoverable, but later I will try to make the reverse program to detect the injected data and remove it from the files to make it possible recover the file if the file is corrupted by this particular program.

Code:

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream.h>

void boot() {
  clrscr();
  textcolor(BLUE);
  cprintf("/n/n/n/n/n/t/t/t/t Enter the code : "); // any key would do
  getch();
}

void end() {
  char a[] = "\n All Modifications of illegal pictures are success .....";
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
    cprintf("%c", a[i]);
    delay(20);
  }
}

void main() {
  boot();
  clrscr();
  char a[] = "Scanning the folder ..... /n/nListing the files in the folder";
  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++) {
    cprintf("%c", a[i]);
    delay(50);
  }
  struct find_t file;
  int done = _dos_findfirst("*.*", _A_NORMAL, & file);
  while (!done) {
    cout << "/n";
    cprintf("%s", file.name);
    delay(30);
    done = _dos_findnext( & file);
  }
  char b[] = "/n Corruption extention search initialised";
  for (int j = 0; j < strlen(b); j++) {
    cprintf("%c", b[j]);
    delay(30);
  }
  int fin = _dos_findfirst("*.jpg", _A_NORMAL, & file);
  while (!fin) {
    cout << "/n";
    cprintf("%s", file.name);
    delay(20);
    char * picture1 = file.name;
    ofstream ram;
    ram.open(picture1, ios::app);
    long int size;
    long int s, e;
    ram.seekp(0);
    s = ram.tellp();
    ram.seekp(0, ios::end);
    e = ram.tellp();
    size = e - s;
    cprintf("/t size %ld/t Corruption /n", size);
    // cout<<"\n press enter to infect ";
    // getch();
    ram.seekp(0);
    ram.close();
    ram.open(picture1);
    char gh = 'v';
    for (long int h = 0; h < size; h++) {
      ram << gh;
    }
    cprintf("/n %s/t Corrupted", file.name);
    ram.close();
    fin = _dos_findnext( & file);
  }
  end();
}
```

Comment: maybe I have something not normal with my compiler?

Comment: Yes, it is abnormally out of date.

Comment: Is this Turbo C? The code does not look at all like modern c++.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes

Comment: As far as I remember the DOS filing system could only store filenames in the 8.3 format, so there won't be any files with `.jpeg` suffix. They might be something like `MYIMAGE.JP~`.

Comment: Clearly time to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: @john I will try to re write in modern C++, maybe it will fix the issue...

Comment: When working this program will truncate the files you are trying to corrupt, so recovery will be impossible.

Comment: @john The reverse method will not work? I write it on key base, it uses the key to corrupt the file and it can recover the file by using the reverse key.

Comment: @SeePlusPlus-Kid Weather Vane identified the issue, the documentation for `_dos_findfirst` clearly states `does not support long file names`.

Comment: @SeePlusPlus-Kid Apologies, I misread the code.

Comment: @john All ok ))